Is this a kind of generalized Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem?
Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable.
It's true that
$$ \dfrac{1}{\nu(G)}\int_G f d \nu \leq f(x) \mbox{ for a.a. } x \in G$$
with $G \subset X$ a measurable set.
I saw that this statement is valid even if $\nu(G) = \infty$. Is it right? I'm thinking this is a kind of generalized Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem since $X$ is a arbitrary set.
Is this result available in any book? Thank you for references.

This is very false. You should be easily able to find a counter example.
